# Add-on Installer for multiple application IDs

Tags: java, install4j

I'm wondering if it's possible to build an add-on Installer for multiple Application IDs. We have two different regular installers, with different IDs, but a lot of possible add-ons for both regular installers. That would be amazing :-)

Thanks ! 
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not configurable directly, but you can use a "Run script" action  in the "Startup" node of the add-on installer to check for other installer applications like this:

```
ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo[] applicationInfos =
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById("<other app ID>");
```

then ask the user which application should be the target and then call

```
context.setInstallationDirectory(applicationInfo.getInstallationDirectory());
```

for the selected application before proceeding with the installation.

Comment: Thank you for that really quick answer!

Comment: Those Add-On Setups will be installed only in unattended mode, so there cant be any user interaction. Is it possible to write the targeted application ID in the response.varfile, and the Add-On will use this? Like I allready do it with the sys.installationDir

Comment: Yes, you can do that. If the variable in the response file is named "targetAppId", you can get it via `(String)context.getVariable("targetAppId")` and use that value to get the target directory from the `ApplicationRegistry`.

Comment: Sounds amazing. But I can not build such a setup, with the error message: applicationInfo cannot be resolved. No matter if the ID is hardcoded or part of the response.varfile. Sorry for asking again :D, but I think I'm pretty close to it !

Comment: applicationInfo is an instance of `ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo` that was mentioned in the first code snippet. I did not write all the logic. You need to handle the case where there are multiple installations of the same application ID and the case where there are none.